# How to limit results by SUM

Tags: sql, mysql, date, sum, limit

I have a table of events called `event`. For the purpose of this question it only has one field called `date`.

The following query returns me a number of events that are happening on each date for the next 14 days:

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT( ev.date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) as short_date,
   count(*) as date_count
FROM event ev
WHERE ev.date >= NOW()
GROUP BY short_date
ORDER BY ev.start_date ASC
LIMIT 14
```

The result could be as follows:

```
+------------+------------+
| short_date | date_count |
+------------+------------+
| 2010-03-14 |          1 | 
| 2010-03-15 |          2 | 
| 2010-03-16 |          9 | 
| 2010-03-17 |          8 | 
| 2010-03-18 |         11 | 
| 2010-03-19 |         14 | 
| 2010-03-20 |         13 | 
| 2010-03-21 |          7 | 
| 2010-03-22 |          2 | 
| 2010-03-23 |          3 | 
| 2010-03-24 |          3 | 
| 2010-03-25 |          6 | 
| 2010-03-26 |         23 | 
| 2010-03-27 |         14 | 
+------------+------------+
14 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Let's say I want to dislay these events by date. At the same time I only want to display a maximum of 10 at a time. How would I do this?

Somehow I need to limit this result by the SUM of the date_count field but I do not know how.

Anybody run into this problem before?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edited:
The extra requirement (crucial one, oops) which I forgot in my original post, is that I only want whole days.
ie. Given the limit is 10, it would only return the following rows:

```
+------------+------------+
| short_date | date_count |
+------------+------------+
| 2010-03-14 |          1 | 
| 2010-03-15 |          2 | 
| 2010-03-16 |          9 | 
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I think your query won't do what you expect if there is a day without any events.

Comment: If no events occur on a particular date, then that date row would simply not appear, which is OK for my purposes

Comment: Are you saying, that when you start adding the date_count on the 14th, you will stop on the 16th since 1+2+9>=10 ??????

Answer (score 3):

1. use a date function to limit the 14 day range of date
2. use limit to display the first 10

---

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT( ev.date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) as short_date,
   count(*) as date_count
FROM event ev
WHERE ev.date between NOW() and date_add(now(), interval 14 day)
GROUP BY date(short_date)
ORDER BY ev.start_date ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: That is way too easy! :) which made me re-read my question and realized I left out one crucial aspect. Sorry to you Jacob and lexu let me ammend the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using `LIMIT 0, 10` will work for you.

Comment: That is way too easy! :) which made me re-read my question and realized I left out one crucial aspect. Sorry to you Jacob and lexu let me amend the question.